# Cabal unexpected behaviour when upgrading

Tags: haskell, cabal

```
ramiro@omfg-hello:~$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.2
compiled using version 1.24.2.0 of the Cabal library 
ramiro@omfg-hello:~$ sudo cabal install cabal-install --force-reinstalls
[sudo] password for ramiro: 
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cabal-install-2.4.0.0...
Building cabal-install-2.4.0.0...
Installed cabal-install-2.4.0.0
ramiro@omfg-hello:~$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.2
compiled using version 1.24.2.0 of the Cabal library
```

Indeed i wasn't expecting something like this. I'm stunned.

Edit:

Fixed with @duplode comment

Further edit:

Anybody knows why i'm still getting this?

```
ramiro@omfg-hello:~/Haskell/happstack-server$ sudo cabal new-test all
cabal: unrecognised command: new-test (try --help)
```

At least i get the correct cabal version now

```
ramiro@omfg-hello:~/Haskell/happstack-server$ cabal --v
cabal-install version 2.4.0.0
compiled using version 2.4.0.1 of the Cabal library
```

EditN :

```
ramiro@omfg-hello:~/Haskell/happstack-server$ cabal new-build
/home/ramiro/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org: openBinaryTempFileWithDefaultPermissions: permission denied (Permission denied)
ramiro@omfg-hello:~/Haskell/happstack-server$ sudo cabal new-build
[sudo] password for ramiro: 
Up to date
ramiro@omfg-hello:~/Haskell/happstack-server$
```

Non-sudo vs sudo.

Comment: (1) Do not use `sudo` to run `cabal`. With typical workflows, cabal-install is meant to be ran from your regular user account. (2) Make sure `$HOME/.cabal/bin`, the default location for executables installed with cabal-install, appears in your PATH before the system-wide location of your preexisting cabal-install. (3) Remember you can check where the executable actually is with `which cabal`.

Comment: @duplode Your suggestions worked, thanks! but do you know how to solve my updated problem? the whole point of upgrading cabal was to run the command `new-test`

Comment: Note that, in your edit, you are still running `cabal` with `sudo`.

Comment: Won't work without sudo atm

Comment: "Won't work without sudo atm" -- Exactly how does it fail? If `cabal --v` and `which cabal` show you are indeed using the 2.4.0.0 version installed in your home directory, `cabal new-test` should, in principle, also work.

Comment: Updated question to show how it fails without sudo. Regarding `new-test`  i always get `unrecognised command`

Comment: In all likelihood, you are getting "permission denied" errors because you installed cabal-install using sudo, which set wrong file permissions. Delete the whole `.cabal` directory (using sudo if necessary) and run `cabal install cabal-install` again, this time without using sudo (if it asks you to run `cabal update`, do so).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183477/discussion-between-user3927886-and-duplode).